# How to get the latest active item?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

The following returns all active items.

```
activeItems: Ember.computed('items.@each.status', {
    get() {
        return this.get('items').filter((item) => {
            return item.get('status') === 'active';
        });
    }
})

// Template
{{#each activeItems as |activeItems|}}
  {{activeItem.status}}
{{/each}}
```

All of above works. Now lets say I want to create a computed property that picks out the last `activeItem`. I tried:

```
activeItem: Ember.computed('activeItems', {
  get() {
    return this.get('activeItems').lastObject;
  }
}),

// Template
{{activeItem.status}} <-- returns nothing
```

Why is this and how can I get it to work?

Comment: Is `item.get('active') === 'active'` in your actual code, or is that just a typo here on SO?

Comment: Whoops, typo. Made the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 problems:

1. Your computed property has the incorrect dependent key. By only relying on `activeItems`, the problem will only update when the `activeItems` property returns a new object, not when the contents are updated. You should be watching `activeItems.lastObject`.
2. `lastObject` is a computed property, which means you might not be able to access it without using Ember's `get()` function.

Try this:

```
activeItem: Ember.computed('activeItems.lastObject', {
    get() {
        return this.get('activeItems.lastObject');
    }
})
```

Or, for the shorthand:

```
activeItem: Ember.computed.reads('activeItems.lastObject')
```